# What is the best way to incorporate Siteminder SSO with the WebSphere Liberty Profile Buildpack?

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

We have a use case where all the apps staged and run with the WebSphere Liberty Profile Buildpack have to authenticate with LDAP and a SiteMinder SSO Proxy.

We have implemented this feature by configuring a TAI in Liberty and pushing the app as a server package.

*We don't want to push server packages for each app*

> How should we package the features like `ldapRegistry-3.0`, the TAI `library` and the associated `trustAssociation` server configuration so that all the apps staged by the buildpack inherit this configuration without pushing server packages. Can this be done with a user feature ?

-cheers,
Rohit Kelapure

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three options:

1. Deploy your application with configuration as a [server directory](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications) instead.
2. Fork and modify the [Liberty buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack) to your needs.
3. Create a [.profile.d](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/deployingapps.html#customize_dep) script (as part of your application) that adds a `server.xml` with your configuration into a [configDropins](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=cord&product=was-nd-mp&topic=twlp_setup_dropins) directory of the Liberty server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no other way to setup the other security mechanisms (TAI Library & trustAssociateion server config) without pushing a server package or pushing a server directory.  See (1) for more details on protecting resources in Liberty.

If you were just adding Liberty features or needed to specify a different set of features, then you could set the *JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY* environment variable and restage the app:

```
$ cf set-env myapp JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY "app_archive: {features: [ldapRegistry-3.0]}"
$ cf restage myapp
```

For more information on other options for pushing Liberty applications, see (2) below.

(1) https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/security/resource_server/index.html#r_oauth_was_wasl

(2) https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications